# Creating a default manifest for git-repo

Tags: git, repository, git-repo

I'm trying to use git repo for my own project. I understand I have to create a default.xml file and using to link to all the repositories available but It's not clear how to do that.
I tried creating a simple xml file and put in on a server. I also added 2 remote configurations and projects.

From what I read the default.xml file must also be in a repository but this step is not clear.

When I try to use the command repo init -u http:// my_custom_url /manifest/ I get a curl download error.

Any advice or steps I have to take in order to create the default manifest ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `default.xml` must be in its own git repository.

Easiest way to understand how `repo` works is to see how Android project (guys who created it in first place) do it.

You should init Android example of manifest as described [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html):

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

You can then download Android source tree using `repo sync`, but it may take a while and 10GB+ of disk space and is not strictly necessary for your investigation, but if you do it, you will understand it better.

Then, take a look at directory `.repo` - inside you will find manifest git repository checked out.

I would suggest taking this as working example, and then removing everything you don't want or don't need and tweaking to your needs.

Comment: I know about android example but that is not enought. Do I have to create an bare git repository and commit the default xml in it ?

Comment: `repo init -u url` expects url for manifest repo that `git clone url` can understand. So, certainly, it does not have to be bare repo on a server, but once everything said and done, it better be

Answer (score 3):

First, you should create a manifest git repository. The manifest repository contains default.xml, which explains your project.

Then, use `repo init -u "your manifest repository path"` and `repo sync` in client.

Please refer the post below.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-Googles-repo-command-in-your-own-projects